# Python- extract 2 values from each dictinary in the list ,that contains 2 lists

Tags: python

I have the following json:

```
    {
"error": null,
"page": "1",
"per_page": "1000",
"results": [
    {
        "cves": [
            {
                "cve_id": "CVE-2016-1583",
                "href": "https://www.redhat.com/security/data/cve/CVE-2016-1583.html"
            },
            {
                "cve_id": "CVE-2016-5195",
                "href": "https://www.redhat.com/security/data/cve/CVE-2016-5195.html"
            }
        ],
        "description": "The kernel packages contain the Linux kernel, the core of any Linux operating\nsystem.\n\nSecurity Fix(es):\n\n* A race condition was  With this update, a set of patches has been applied that fix\nthese problems. As a result, the time stamps of GFS2 files are now handled\ncorrectly. (BZ#1374861)",
        "errata_id": "RHSA-2016:2124",
        "hosts_applicable_count": 0,
        "hosts_available_count": 0,
        "id": "81ee41e6-2a3a-4475-a88e-088dee956787",
        "issued": "2016-10-28",
        "packages": [
            "kernel-2.6.18-416.el5.i686",

        ],
        "reboot_suggested": true,
        "severity": "Important",
        "solution": "For details on how to apply this update, which includes the changes described in\nthis advisory, refer to:\n\nhttps://access.redhat.com/articles/11258\n\nThe system must be rebooted for this update to take effect.",
        "summary": "An update for kernel is now available for Red Hat Enterprise Linux 5.\n\nRed Hat Product Security
```

I want to extract the values of errata_id and summary (just the RHEL version)
which i want to place as anew dictionary ,ie: RHSA-2016:2098:Red Hat Enterprise Linux 5

i was able to extract the errats list ,but not with the summary as a dictionary just as a list :

```
ERRATA_ID_LIST = []
for errata_ids in erratas_by_cve_dic['results']:
    ERRATA_ID = errata_ids['errata_id']
    ERRATA_ID_LIST.append(ERRATA_ID
```

Comment: What kind of output are you looking for? I am unable to understand what you are trying to ask here

Comment: The json You posted here is not a valid json. Please review it

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you want to create a dictionary with {id, summary}, so you can do:

```
ERRATA_ID_DICT = {}
for element in erratas_by_cve_dic['results']:
    ERRATA_ID_DICT[element['errata_id']] = element['summary']
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two possible approaches:

1) using a for loop, like you did, but putting data into a dictionary:

```
errata = {}
for errata_ids in erratas_by_cve_dic['results']:
  errata_id = errata_ids['errata_id']
  summary = errata_ids['summary']
  errata[errata_id] = summary
```

or, shorter but possibly less clear:

```
errata = {}
for errata_ids in erratas_by_cve_dic['results']:
  errata[errata_ids['errata_id']] = errata_ids['summary']
```

2) using dictionary comprehension:

```
errata = { errata_ids['errata_id']: errata_ids['summary'] for errata_ids in erratas_by_cve_dic['results'] }
```

I like the 2nd method more, as it is not only shorter, but also more pythonic (ie. using Python idiom).